# Capistrano: SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm using `capistrano` 3.2.1 with Rails 4.1 application. I'm trying to install gem from my github repo. But it's not work. I have no idea what's going on. When I run `ssh -T git@github.com` on my server it's success. But when I run `cap production deploy` I get following errors.

```
[aff68e9c] Finished in 9.435 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [45eeecaf] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 2.0.0-p451@rails-4.1 do bundle install --binstubs /opt/www/moto/shared/bin --path /opt/www/moto/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet on 107.170.74.157
DEBUG [45eeecaf] Command: cd /opt/www/moto/releases/20140429073253 && /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 2.0.0-p451@rails-4.1 do bundle install --binstubs /opt/www/moto/shared/bin --path /opt/www/moto/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Warning, new version of rvm available '1.25.24', you are using older version '1.25.22'.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Host key verification failed.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    and the repository exists.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Retrying git clone 'git@github.com:sdfsd/mongoid_auto_increment.git' "/opt/www/moto/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid_auto_increment-be1b78474ac71203d9549e08e5b3158473ff391d" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git@github.ssdfsdf/mongoid_auto_increment.git' "/opt/www/moto/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid_auto_increment-be1b78474ac71203d9549e08e5b3158473ff391d" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /opt/www/moto/releases/20140429073253 has failed.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    and the repository exists.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Retrying git clone 'git@github.sfafsd/mongoid_auto_increment.git' "/opt/www/moto/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid_auto_increment-be1b78474ac71203d9549e08e5b3158473ff391d" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git@github.sdfsafa/mongoid_auto_increment.git' "/opt/www/moto/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid_auto_increment-be1b78474ac71203d9549e08e5b3158473ff391d" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /opt/www/moto/releases/20140429073253 has failed.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Host key verification failed.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Retrying git clone 'git@github.sfsafas/mongoid_auto_increment.git' "/opt/www/moto/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid_auto_increment-be1b78474ac71203d9549e08e5b3158473ff391d" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git@github.sdfsafs/mongoid_auto_increment.git' "/opt/www/moto/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid_auto_increment-be1b78474ac71203d9549e08e5b3158473ff391d" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /opt/www/moto/releases/20140429073253 has failed.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    and the repository exists.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Retrying git clone 'git@github.sdfsa/mongoid_auto_increment.git' "/opt/www/moto/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid_auto_increment-be1b78474ac71203d9549e08e5b3158473ff391d" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (3/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git@github.sfsadfs/mongoid_auto_increment.git' "/opt/www/moto/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid_auto_increment-be1b78474ac71203d9549e08e5b3158473ff391d" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /opt/www/moto/releases/20140429073253 has failed.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    and the repository exists.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Retrying git clone 'git@github.sdfsfsa/mongoid_auto_increment.git' "/opt/www/moto/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid_auto_increment-be1b78474ac71203d9549e08e5b3158473ff391d" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (3/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git@github.sfdsaf/mongoid_auto_increment.git' "/opt/www/moto/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid_auto_increment-be1b78474ac71203d9549e08e5b3158473ff391d" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /opt/www/moto/releases/20140429073253 has failed.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Host key verification failed.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Retrying git clone 'git@github.dsffsd/mongoid_auto_increment.git' "/opt/www/moto/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid_auto_increment-be1b78474ac71203d9549e08e5b3158473ff391d" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (3/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git@github.sdfsfs/mongoid_auto_increment.git' "/opt/www/moto/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid_auto_increment-be1b78474ac71203d9549e08e5b3158473ff391d" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /opt/www/moto/releases/20140429073253 has failed.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    and the repository exists.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Git error: command `git clone
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    'git@github.sdfdsfs/mongoid_auto_increment.git'
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    "/opt/www/moto/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/mongoid_auto_increment-be1b78474ac71203d9549e08e5b3158473ff391d"
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    /opt/www/moto/releases/20140429073253 has failed.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [45eeecaf]    and the repository exists.
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 11
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Any idea? if u need more info let me know.

Comment: you add ssh keys from server to github repo deploy-keys?

Comment: @Monk_Code yep. Already added.

Comment: try clone you repo from server.

Comment: Ok. Wait .............

Comment: No it's public. BTW thank u for trying to help me :D

Comment: OMG. Same ....... It's not work ...

Comment: try change `git@github.com:zolzaya/mongoid_auto_increment.git` to `git://github.com/zolzaya/mongoid_auto_increment.git`

Comment: Ooook. Deploying ....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51651/discussion-between-zeck-and-monk-code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
git@github.com:zolzaya/mongoid_auto_increment.git
```

to

```
git://github.com/zolzaya/mongoid_auto_increment.git
```

This should work.